# GRUB not showing up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 alongside windows 8.1 and it was working fine until I ran the CHKDSK command in windows now when I restart the PC, there is no GRUB screen and the PC boots directly into windows. I used the boot-repair-disk but no luck. My secure boot is off and I also tried to reinstall GRUB using [this](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) but still no luck. I know there are A LOT of threads similar to this but I have tried methods given in several of those but no luck :( Here is the [URL](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10609818/) I got after using the recommended repair option in Boot-repair:

Comment: What was the CHKDSK command that you ran in Windows?

Comment: Did you try the advice given at the end of the boot-info that you posted?

Comment: I ran simple CHKDSK command and @OrganicMarble yes I have done that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Ubuntu Live CD, launch a terminal console and type:

`sudo su` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

`gparted` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Observe what is the Ubuntu partition. Probably it will be **/dev/sda2**. Assuming that, then, it closes gparted and (sudo is not required because you are already root with **sudo su**):

`mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

`mount -B /dev /mnt/dev`  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

`chroot /mnt`   <kbd>Enter</kbd>

`grub-install /dev/sda` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

`reboot`  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then you will have grub2 re-installed.

Comment: Thank you ! surprisingly it worked even though i had re installed grub several times using other commands

Comment: You're welcome. I'm pretty glad for your success. I reinstall grub always with this method.